# center text in button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created this button, however i can't seem to center the text. i've set the line-height, but does not seem to work what is wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12048/

css

```
a.round {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    margin-bottom: 180px;
}

#icon-buy {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

Comment: It looks vertically centered to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think have to align the `<i>` to get the look you are after.

```
#icon-buy {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12050/)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this may be:

```
/* setting button as relative position*/ 
a.round{    
line-height:36px;
position:relative;
padding: 10px 20px 10px 60px;
}

#icon-buy{
font-size: 35px;
position:absolute;
left:20px;
}
```

check output here: https://jsfiddle.net/kumaramit24apps/yLsqq1o2/1/